# Installed date for an iOS app using Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to find the date an app was installed on a device using Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use UserDefaults?

You could check for a key let's say "installDate", if it does't exist it means it's the first time your launching the app and you'll set the installDate as the current date. If it does exist you know that the app was launched already.

Comment: But won't this work for when you open the app for the first time?

Comment: It's the only way, you have no way to know when the user bought/downloaded the App. You can only know when he first launched it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding:

```
var urlToDocumentsFolder = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User).First();
var creationDate = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetAttributes(urlToDocumentsFolder.Path).CreationDate;
```